# Set measurable with respect to one product measure but not with respect to another

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

For $p \in (0,1)$, let $\mu_p$ be the measure on $\{0,1\}$ given by $\mu_p(\{1\}) = 1 - \mu_p(\{0\}) = p$. We can extend $\mu_p$ to a product measure on the countably infinite product $\{0,1\}^\omega$, which we also denote by $\mu_p$.

> Is there a subset of $\{0,1\}^\omega$ which is measurable with respect to $\mu_p$ but not with respect to $\mu_q$, for some $p,q \in (0,1)$?

And a follow up question, in case the answer to the preceding question is affirmative:

> Which subsets of $\{0,1\}^\omega$ are measurable with respect to all $\mu_p$ measures?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is not mathoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, yes, many such subsets exist.  For instance, let $A_p\subset\{0,1\}^\omega$ denote the set of sequences $(x_n)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N x_n/N$ converges to $p$ as $N\to\infty$.  Then the sets $A_p$ are disjoint for different values of $p$, and $\mu_q(A_p)=1$ if $p=q$ and $0$ otherwise.  In particular, every subset of $A_p$ is $\mu_q$-measurable if $p\neq q$, but not every subset of $A_p$ is $\mu_p$-measurable.

For your second question, it follows from the previous paragraph that $E\subseteq \{0,1\}^\omega$ is $\mu_p$-measurable for all $p$ iff $E\cap A_p$ differs from a Borel set by a $\mu_p$-null set for each $p$.  This is probably as explicit a condition as you can hope to get.  Note that in particular, the sets $A_p$ are disjoint, so you are free to choose $E\cap A_p$ independently for each value of $p$ when building such a set $E$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a nonmeasurable subset of $A_p$? I'm not sure the Vitali construction immediately works here.

Comment: You can construct one by transfinite induction.  There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ Borel sets, $2^{\aleph_0}$ Borel null sets, and $2^{\aleph_0}$ points in $A_p$.  So by a transfinite induction of length $2^{\aleph_0}$, you can construct a set $E\subset A_p$ such that for each Borel $B\subseteq A_p$ and each Borel null set $N\subseteq A_p$, $E\mathbin{\Delta} B$ is not contained in $N$.